# Price of items using classes in python

Tags: python, class

Write a class called Product. The class should have fields called name, amount, and price,
holding the product’s name, the number of items of that product in stock, and the regular
price of the product. There should be a method get_price that receives the number of
items to be bought and returns a the cost of buying that many items, where the regular price is charged for orders of less than 10 items, a 10% discount is applied for orders of between
10 and 99 items, and a 20% discount is applied for orders of 100 or more items. There should
also be a method called make_purchase that receives the number of items to be bought and
decreases amount by that much.

My first method is working fine. However when i had the second method it does not do what is required.

```
class Product:

  def __init__(self,amount,price):
    self.amount=amount
    self.price=price

  def get_price(self):
    while self.amount>=0:
      if self.amount<10:
        return self.amount*self.price
      elif 10<=self.amount<99:
        return 0.9*self.amount*self.price
      else:
        return 0.8*self.amount*self.price

  def make_purchase(self):
    return int(input('Number of elements to buy'))-self.amount

costs=Product(int(input('Digit amount of items\n')),int(input('Digit price of items\n')))
purchases=Product(int(input('Digit amount of items to buy\n')),int(input('Digit price of items\n')))
print('Final costs = ',costs.get_price())
print('Elements to buy=',purchases.make_purchase())
```

Comment: How, exactly, does it "not do what is required"? What error messages does running the second method produce?

Comment: the second function does not return number of items to buy minus the object self.amount

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code requires hand input, and you're not specific about what's wrong with the output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `Product class` that does what is required.
Then you create some `Product` instances of this class.
You use these instances of `Product` to call the methods of the class `Product`, and obtain the desired behavior.

It was rather awkward to input all values each time, so I wrote a few tests that did not require input.

You probably need to decide what to do when the quantity of items to purchase exceeds the available stock of the item; no indications were given on how to handle this case.

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, name, amount, price):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
        self.price = price

    def get_price(self, number_to_be_bought):
        discount = 0
        if number_to_be_bought < 10:
            pass
        elif 10 <= number_to_be_bought < 99:
            discount = 10
        else:
            discount = 20
        price = (100 - discount) / 100 * self.price
        return price * number_to_be_bought

    def make_purchase(self, quantity):
        self.amount -= quantity


# name = input('name:')
# amount = int(input('Digit amount of items'))
# price = int(input('Digit price of items'))

name, amount, price = 'shoes', 200, 33

shoes = Product(name, amount, price)
# quantity = int(input('Digit amount of items to buy'))

q1 = 4
print(f'cost for {q1} {shoes.name} = {shoes.get_price(q1)}')
shoes.make_purchase(q1)
print(f'remaining stock: {shoes.amount}\n')

q2 = 12
print(f'cost for {q2} {shoes.name} = {shoes.get_price(q2)}')
shoes.make_purchase(q2)
print(f'remaining stock: {shoes.amount}\n')

q3 = 112
print(f'cost for {q3} {shoes.name} = {shoes.get_price(q3)}')
shoes.make_purchase(q3)
print(f'remaining stock: {shoes.amount}\n')
```

**output:**

```
cost for 4 shoes = 132.0
remaining stock: 196

cost for 12 shoes = 356.4
remaining stock: 184

cost for 112 shoes = 2956.8
remaining stock: 72
```